# display incorrect/different on mobile (responsive)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, responsive-design, responsiveness

i have a ruby app which i am embedding an iframe to display content. on a computer the screen the display is perfect and responsive. if i shrink the browser window everything scales to  size and the buttons look appear correctly NOW if i pull the same page in my mobile phone, everything is small and the fields/buttons are hard to read.

I have tried putting the iframe in a bootstrap container, adjusting the iframe settings but nothing works. the domain is [www.drinkpgh.com](http://www.drinkpgh.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the viewport meta tag to ensure a website is rendered properly. Add this inside the HTML `<head>` tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Should solve your problem.

Read more about it: [Viewport Meta Tag - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: that worked thanks! I will accept the answer in 7 mins when I am allowed